# Роутинг в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, роутинг

Начал познавать данный фреймворк.
Возник вопрос. Есть такой роутинг:

```
Route::get('/tasks/{task}', function ($id) {
    $task = DB::table('tasks')->find($id);
    return view('tasks.show', compact("task"));
});
```

Объясните что означает `{task}`.
На месте этой записи выводится id записи из БД. Но не пойму почему запись именно такая. Почему task? И что за фигурные скобки? Это некий шаблон?

Comment: Все что будет после `/tasks/` интерпетируется как `task` [Route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-parameters)

Comment: Вы можете указать что-угодно вместо **task**. Во время обработки, вместо `{some text here}` подставляют часть URLа (по регулярном выражении) и в итоге берут ту часть, которая стоит на месте `{task}` в урле.

Answer (score 1):

{task} - wildcard, проще говоря, ты можешь туда влепить что угодно, все равно. Когда в контроллере будешь обращаться, он у тебя найдет, что есть такой то wildcard и его значение такое-то.

Если по какой-то причине, тебе надо гетом выкидывать сразу два значения, к примеру /{id}/{name} то есть смысл называть их не как попало, а так, чтобы было понятно. Тогда в контроллере сможешь обратиться к ним как $id и $name соотв.

Чтобы лучше понять попробуй контроллеры посоздавать.

Comment: Мне всё равно не совсем понятно для чего это нужно

Comment: смотри, у тебя есть шаблон к примеру name.blade.php - в нем какая нибудь ерунда, но динамически выводится какое нибудь имя. Страница имеет вид example.com/name/pasha. в web.php у тебя есть строчка Route::get('/name/{name}', 'MySomeController@show'); То есть ты указываешь, что делать, когда такой-то путь открыт, в данном случае открывается MySomeController и в нем функция show($name) которая возвращает вьюшку с переменной $NameInURL = $name; return view('name', compact("NameInURL")); и теперь во вьбшке мы можем влепить {{ $NameInURL }} и увидеть pasha

Comment: Понял, спасибо)